# Analysis and summary or ecological samples

Tags: r, statistics, dataset, bar-chart

I am working on this dataset :

```
dat<-read.table(text = "Sample    Pho    Spec
         1    FagS     Lic1
         2    FagS     Lic1
         3    FagS     Lic2
         5    QueP     Lic2
         6    QueP     Lic1
         7    FagS     Lic1
         8    FraE     Lic3
         9    FraE     Lic4, header=T)
```

And I would known the specie (Spec) diversity by phorophytes (Pho) and to be able to ponderate this information by comparing the SpecDiv by Pho versus the quantity of sample (NuOfSa) by Pho.

Example :

```
Pho     SpecDiv    NuOfSa    Ratio
FagS    2          4         0.5
QueP    2          2         1
FraE    2          2         1
```

The aim would be to plot this information through a "barplot" in order to compare species diversity between phorophytes.

Many thanks for your helpful help ;)

R.

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Regarding the plot part it is not clear how you want to show the `ratio`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, "rowSums" was what I missed ! I looked for that, but certainly with the wrong keywords ! 
For the plot part, I am not yet sure of what I will do with theses data obtained through a not very clearly sampled protocol...
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a base solution (after replacing the missing double quote in the example code):

```
temp <- cbind( SpecDiv= rowSums( with(dat, table( Pho, Spec))>0 ),
 NuOfSa=with(dat, table( Pho)))
final <- cbind( temp, ratio=temp[,1]/temp[,2])
final
#--------
     SpecDiv NuOfSa ratio
FagS       2      4   0.5
FraE       2      2   1.0
QueP       2      2   1.0
```

The most difficult part was figuring our the meaning of the phrase "specie (Spec) diversity by phorophytes (Pho)". In the future you ought to explain your domain specific conventions a bit more thoroughly so that non-ecologists will be able to offer better assistance. The notion of collapsing good data on counts to present or absent seemed to result in a serious loss of data to my way of understanding the statistical perspective. I question whether having an "occasional" (in the language of "birders") in the observation set really qualifies as increasing the "species diversity".

And the plotting task awaits a better description of `<what>` is to be plotted against `<what>`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dat)`), grouped by "Pho", we get the `length` of `unique` "Spec" (`uniqueN`), and the number of rows (`.N`), then get the "ratio" by dividing one over the another

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[,list(SpecDiv=uniqueN(Spec), NuOfSa=.N) , 
                    Pho][, ratio:= SpecDiv/NuOfSa][]
#     Pho SpecDiv NuOfSa ratio
#1: FagS       2      4   0.5
#2: QueP       2      2   1.0
#3: FraE       2      2   1.0
```